# How to check the values of multiple variables at once?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, if-statement

I need to check the value of all 3 variables(username, password, secret). If a value is NA then I need to execute a print statement or else some condition needs to be executed.

```
Example 1:

username = person1
password = pass1
secret   = NA

Example 2:

username = person1
password = pass1
secret   = secret1
```

**Example**

```
#value = Check all 3 variables for NA value
if value is NA:
   print("NA Block")
else:
    print("Value Block")
    #Calling some function
```

How to check the value of those variables all at once?

Comment: What's the problem with `or` logical operator. `username == 'NA' or password == 'NA' or secret == 'NA'` ?

Comment: What to do if I have more than 3 variables?.@tbhaxor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `in` operator to check whether a value is `"NA"`. Like so:

```py
if "NA" in (username, password, secret):  
    print("NA Block")
else:
    print("Value Block")
    #Calling some function
```